# Laravel Class not found + Abstract Class

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm having an issue using a abstract class in laravel. I'm just following this tutorial http://culttt.com/2014/03/17/eloquent-tricks-better-repositories but when I execure the code I got an error "Class not found".

I've binded the class in the service provider here's my code

RepositoriesServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoriesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public function register()
   {
    $this->app->bind(
   'Repositories\User\UserRepository',
   'Repositories\User\EloquentUserRepository',
   'Repositories\User\AbstractEloquentRepository'

   );
  }

}

?>
```

EloquentUserRepository.php

```
namespace Repositories\User;

use User;

class EloquentUserRepository extends AbstractEloquentRepository implements UserRepository{

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(User $model){

        $this->model = $model;

    }


    public function find($id){

        return User::find($id);

    }


    public function create($input){

        return User::create($input);

    }

}

?>
```

AbstractEloquentRepository.php

```
<?php 

  abstract class AbstractEloquentRepository{

    public function all(){

        return $this->model->all();

    }


}

?>
```

UserRepository.php

```
<?php

 namespace Repositories\User;

 interface UserRepository{

    public function all();

    public function find($id);

    public function create($input);
}

?>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
  use Repositories\User\UserRepository as User;

  class UserController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */


    public function __construct(User $user){

        $this->user = $user;

    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
      return $this->user->all();
    }

    // public function showWelcome()
    // {
    //  return View::make('hello');
    // }






}
```

Comment: Here's the error I got http://screencast.com/t/GysgRTea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a namespace in your `AbstractEloquentRepository.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `php artisan dump-autoload` and `composer dump-autoload` in terminal to regenerate all classes files. May this will solve your problem.

Comment: I got this error. Cannot instantiate interface Repositories\User\UserRepository

Answer (score 0):

Try binding them one at a time...

```
$this->app->bind('Repositories\User\UserRepository', function(){
   return new \Repositories\User\UserRepository();
}
```

Comment: I tried it and there's no luck. I got this error message "Cannot instantiate interface Repositories\User\UserRepository"

Comment: you'll need to show us your controller and the class code